# Where do I put macros (besides in normal) so they are always available in word 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-addins

I had a bunch of macros that I had in  C:\Users\userx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates that were always available in word 2010 but since upgrade to word 2013 I cannot run them.  Word apparently does not automatically load them anymore.  I used to just do alt F8 and pick from the list.  I also had a few added to the quick options bar but they are gone also.

Searched this site and MS website and can't seem to find a solution.  Is there another location that I need to move the files containing the macros to or is there some other action that I need to take so I can run them again?

My guess is this is already answered here and I am just not searching for the right things.  My apologies if that is the case, please just point me to the appropriate post.

Comment: Does [**This**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/where-are-my-custom-templates-in-office-2013-HA103478764.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a shortcut to the templates containing your macros in the following location

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP
```

That will make your macros available whenever Word opens and restore the `Alt+F8` functionality you're looking for. If you add toolbars to your templates, those will also automatically be attached to the Normal template when you open Word.

Comment: Putting them in the STARTUP folder fixed the problem but for some reason I had to change all .docm to .dotm to get them to work.  Is this something new or did I just miss something?  Either way I got everything to work properly now.

Comment: Not sure if that's new, but it makes sense. DOCM files are macro-enabled documents, whereas DOTM files are macro-enabled templates. I can't remember the details off hand, but different events fire when Word opens a template vs. a document. One of those is to create a new document based on that template. Since DOCM files aren't templates, the `New` event wouldn't fire, and wouldn't prompt any inheritance.